# Second regex match statement get an error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

While this code run perfectly:

```
def center2 (a)
  c = a.match('(?<=A).*$')
  return c
end
```

Why this code got an error:

```
def center2 (a)
  b = a.match('(?<=_).*$')
  c = b.match('(?<=A).*$')
  return c
end
```

with this error

> undefined method `match', Did you mean?  catch

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: first regex supposed to get all the string after first '_' and before last '.', and for then for the result I was trying to use another regex which get all string after 'A'.

Comment: @Stefan problem is solved now. the match function doesn't return the string, but the matchdata object. So I need to use the second match function on the first element.

Comment: negams, you still haven't answered @Stefan's question (nevermind that there is an accepted solution). Since your code raises an exception how is the reader supposed to figure out what you are trying to achieve? You should edit to state (at the beginning) your objective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match) method returns a [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html) object (or `nil` if there was no match). You seem to want to run the second match on the first match string value. So, just use

```
def center2 (a)
  b = a[/(?<=_).*$/]
  c = b[/(?<=A).*$/]
end
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/GiBY9s)

Actually, if these patterns are placeholders for more complicated patterns, and the task is to find a substring after the first `_` and then the rightmost `A`, you may shorten this code to

```
def center2 (a)
  a[/_.*?A\K.*/]
end
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/GiBY9s). Do not forget about `m` modifier if you need to match across lines (`.` does not match line breaks by default). `_` will match the first `_` from the left, `.*?A` will match any 0+ chars as few as possible up to and including the closest `A` and `\K` will omit the matched text and `.*` will match and return any 0+ chars (other than line break chars by default).

Comment: Thank you, this works. I suppose I was performing the second match function on a list and not on a string. Thank you.

Comment: Wiktor used `\K` ("forget everything matched so far") rather than `/(?<=_.*?A).*/` because Ruby does not support variable-length lookbehinds  (lookaheads OK). Alternatively, one could use a capture group:  `a[/_.*?A(.*)/, 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use a regular expression.

```
def grab_end(str)
  idx_ = str.index('_')
  idxA = str.rindex('A')
  idx_ && idxA && (idx_ < idxA) && str[str.rindex('A')+1..-1]
end

grab_end "Now and_then I_like Aeating popcorn" #=> "eating popcorn"
grab_end "Now and_then I_like eating popcorn"  #=> nil
grab_end "Now and then I like Aeating popcorn" #=> nil
grab_end "Now and then I like Aeating_popcorn" #=> false
```